# XML Offset always returned as -1

Tags: java, xml

Hi I am trying to parse given below xml. Here is an XML exceprt:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<eipsiebeldata xmlns="http://www.emeter.com/energyip/eipsiebeldata">
  <product id="Product.1" op="upsert">
    <sfield name="Sales Product Flag" value="Y"/>
    <sfield name="Unit of Measure" value=""/>
    <sfield name="Secondary Asset Type" value=""/>
    <sfield name="Version Status" value=""/>
    <sfield name="Sub Type" value="Pricing Plan"/>
    <sfield name="Type" value="Service"/>
    <sfield name="Sales Service Flag" value="N"/>
    <sfield name="Name" value="Pricing Plan - R2B"/>
    <sfield name="Group Name" value=""/>
    <sfield name="Description" value="Pricing Plan - R2B"/>
    <productAttribute id="ProductAttribute.2" op="upsert">
      <sfield name="Remark" value=""/>
      <sfield name="Status" value="Active"/>
      <sfield name="End Date" value=""/>
      <sfield name="Type Value" value="R2_B"/>
      <sfield name="Name" value="Name"/>
      <sfield name="Start Date" value="01/01/1990 00:00:00"/>
    </productAttribute>
  </product>
</eipsiebeldata>
```

The code that I have written is :

//Creating XML Stream Readers and Filter Reader.

```
xmlsr = inputFactory.createXMLStreamReader(new FileInputStream(
                            file));
                    xmlfsr = inputFactory.createFilteredReader(xmlsr,
                            getStreamFilter(sObjectAdapter));
```

//Stream Filter Implementation.

```
StreamFilter getStreamFilter(final ISObjectAdapter sObjectAdapter) {
    return new StreamFilter() {
        public boolean accept(XMLStreamReader reader) {
            Location loc = reader.getLocation();
            int pos = loc.getCharacterOffset();
            return false;
        }
    };
}
```

The issue is the character offset is always returned as -1. I would like to know the reason behind this. Actually its working in an env with JDK 7 update 27 while its not working in env with JDK 7.0. Is this regarding Java version issue. 
The very same XML I am able to process in JDK7 update 27 env. Please note that XML size is big, is it because of XML size, but again in JDK 7 update 27 env i am able to process the XML as character offset in never returned as -1, while in other env the character offset is always returned as -1. The surprising fact is even when reader cursor moves forward, even in that condition character offset is returned as -1. I would like to know the reason behind this.

Comment: Actually when offset is not -1 then only I start processing parsed document. There is a corresponding if block for the same which I haven't included.

Answer (score 0):

the stax parser shipped with jdk does not implement location. try using [woodstoc](https://github.com/FasterXML/woodstox). this parser supports location information;

Comment: Yeah but its working with JDK Update 21 onwards, but its not working with JDK 7.0.So is this because of JDK version issue

Comment: But in what conditions characterOffset will be returned as -1